# How do I test out all functions of a hero alone?

Tags: overwatch

I'm new to Overwatch and I want to try out the heroes' moves, but I don't know how. Do you go on a private map? I don't want to scan the map, I just want a way to test the hero out, but I don't know if I can do that.

Answer (score 5):

If you go into Training, there is a Practice Range option where you can practice using each hero’s weapons and abilities against training dummies.

[image: Training Menu]